# Mendeley keeps adding month field to my .bib file

Tags: bibtex

I go through and delete all the `month = mmm` fields so that my paper compiles *without* `Last, First (YYYY, mmm)` in the references. But if Mendeley is open (or when it is opened later) it adds back the `month` field. I don't know where it gets the month, because I don't see a month field in the program's right sidebar (maybe it's called "Detail").

How do I stop this? Where do the months come from?

(And OT, but if I find a Mendeley/bibtex expert, how do I prevent Mendeley from writing my .bib in UTF-8? That is also frustrating. :) )

Comment: Which bibliography style do use? It may be easier to reprogram the bibliography style and tell it to ignore any `month` fields.

Comment: @Mico -- I use `chicago` with `natbib`. Is there one that gives `Author (Year)` in body of paper that you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: @RichardHerron, I use `natbib` and `apalike` for that, and \citet{foo} gives an author (year) citation.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell -- Thanks! I think that does it. You saved me from the black hole of biblatex.

Comment: Excellent, though it was really @Mico's solution! Any day you avoid biblatex is a good day :). As a developer of BibDesk, I have no answer to your UTF-8 question, but I can offer sympathies; encoding isn't fun to deal with.

Comment: Nobody but the owners of the proprietary software can help you if you use proprietary tools. But this is off topic here, because you do not ask anything TeX related.